# Why isn't my code calculating the correct total?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods

I'm having trouble trying to find out the running total. Each time I calculate the running total it miscalculates and gives me the incorrect answer. I'm not sure what it is. I cant tell if it has something to do with the method calling I did in main, the if statement in takeOrder or neither.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MyCoffeeHouse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your name?");
        greetCustomer(name);
        double totalPrice = takeOrder(name);
        calculateFinalPrice(totalPrice);
    }

    public static void greetCustomer(String name) {
        // greet customer
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello " + name + ", Welcome to A Cup of Java!");
    }

    public static double takeOrder(String name) { // this method returns
        String[] food = {"coffee", "bagel", "tea", "muffin"};
        double[] price = {3.99, 1.99, 2.99, 4.99};
        double totalprice = 0;
        DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

        for (int index = 0; index < food.length; index++) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Our menu offers: " + food[index] + "(s) which is " + "$"
                + price[index]);
        }

        int numItems =
            Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(name + ", How many items are "
                + "you interested in purchasing?"));

        // running total
        for (int index = 0; index < numItems; index++) {
            String input =
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Which items are you interested in purchasing from "
                    + "our menu: coffee, bagel, tea, or muffin?");

            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(food[index])) {
                totalprice += price[index];
            }
        }
        return totalprice;
    }

    public static void calculateFinalPrice(double totalPrice) {
        double salestax = (totalPrice * 0.07) + totalPrice; // 7% salestax
        double finalprice;
        DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

        int input =
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to dine in?", "Confirm",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        if (input == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            finalprice = totalPrice + (salestax * 0.02);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The final price is $" + finalprice);
        } else {
            DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The final price is $" + dec.format(salestax));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly provide less information? What input are you expecting? What output are you expecting? What output are you seeing? What happened when you debugged? What happened when you walked through the code with an attached debugger/used print statements? What else have you tried? Where does the problem seem to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
double salestax= totalPrice + 0.07; //7% salestax
```

This means you are adding 7 cents in tax, not 7 percent.  To add 7 % you need to multiply the original price by 1.07 or 100% + 7% = 107%

```
double salestax= totalPrice * 1.07; // add 7% salestax
```

When you do

```
finalprice=salestax + 0.02;
```

You are adding 2 cents. Note: at this point you can add another 2% however adding 7% and another 2% is not the same at adding 9% as 1.07 * 1.02 > 1.09.

Comment: thanks! I've changed it but it's still giving me a wrong calculation. I don't know if the method call is not being called correctly or not :/

Comment: Can you give examples of what you input and what you expect to be the output?

Comment: I updated it. My input would be 3 items. The items are 1 muffin,1 tea and 1 bagel and I would like to dine in. I'm still getting $0.00 displayed? I think it has something to do with the double totalprice=0; in the takeOrder method. It's like that is overriding everything else and ignoring my for loop and if statement.so when it returns totalprice it returns 0. The totalprice SHOULD be $9.97 you see what I'm saying? All together(including the salestax and dining in) it should display $10.88 as the total. I hope I explained it well enough :/

Comment: @ASH in your code, you assume the food will be entered in the same order it appears in the array. If it does, you don't do anything. Instead, you could read any number of words in any order and still have it count. To do this you need a nested loop or use a Map data structure to look up a price.

Comment: @ASH this is where using a debugger to debug your code would be helpful in understanding what your code is a tally doing and why.

Answer (score 0):

Get the chosen food item before you loop to test for the price.

```
// First get the input
String input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,//
    "Which items are you interested in purchasing from "
    + "our menu: coffee, bagel, tea, or muffin?");
for(int index=0;index<numItems;index++) {
    // now loop all of the items, and check what was picked.
    if(input.equalsIgnoreCase(food[index])) {
         totalprice+=price[index];
    } 
}
```